# csv module in python troubles

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've read countless threads on here but I'm still unable to figure out exactly how to do this. I'm using the CSV module in python to write data to a csv file. My difficulty is, I've stored the header files in a list (called header) and it contains a variable number of columns. I need to reference each column name so I can write it to my file, which would be easy, except for the fact that it might contain a variable # of columns and I can't figure out how to have a variable # of arrays that I can write to (of course I'm using zip(*header, list1,list2,list3,...) to write to the csv file, but how to generate the list(i) so that header[i] populates the ith list??? I'm sorry for the lack of code, I just can't figure out how to even begin ...

Comment: You need to give us at least some code because your words are not clear enough for us to grasp your problem.  For example, you say header files (do you mean column titles) have a variable number of columns.  Varying when?  During the write?  We need more explanation ideally some attempt at some code.

Comment: Strubby yes a variable # of column titles and id like to use CSV to reference them

Comment: Please show example input and example output to illustrate your requirement. Currently your question is *unclear*.